# Where can I find the global exclusion list in TFVC?

Tags: visual-studio, azure-devops, tfvc

I see a file excluded from TFVC based on a global exclusion list, but I don't know where the global exclusion list lives.

[image]

It looks like `*.user` is excluded.  I have a project ending in `.user`.  I have a `.tfignore` that should include `*.user` but the global exclusion list is overriding it.  Where can I find this list?

I have researched and I couldn't find any info on MS or SO for a global exclusion list in TFVC.